# Orange - Text install issue

Tags: orange

I cannot install the Text add-on.

How can I fix this?

[image: Orange - Text install issue]

Comment: This looks a bug. There is an open issue on the Orange Issue Tracker: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/3720

Comment: Thanks, Stephen! More details. I see this issue only on Win 10 System 32.